# redirect command error output to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash, loops, redirect, terminal

i run ( host ) command on a list of subdomain's to get the ip for each domain ... i want to ignore the  not found: 3(NXDOMAIN) result
i try with

```
for i in $(cat no-http.txt) ; do host $i 2>/dev/null; done
```

output :

```
e1792.dscx.akamaiedge.net has address 104.79.236.53
e1792.dscx.akamaiedge.net has IPv6 address 2a02:26f0:fa00:597::700
e1792.dscx.akamaiedge.net has IPv6 address 2a02:26f0:fa00:5a3::700
akamai-apigateway-warp3pl.tesla.com is an alias for akamai-apigateway-warp3pl.tesla.com.edgekey.net.
akamai-apigateway-warp3pl.tesla.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e1792.dscx.akamaiedge.net.
e1792.dscx.akamaiedge.net has address 104.79.236.53
e1792.dscx.akamaiedge.net has IPv6 address 2a02:26f0:fa00:5a3::700
e1792.dscx.akamaiedge.net has IPv6 address 2a02:26f0:fa00:597::700
Host olt.tesla.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
^CHost kamai-apigateway-warp3pl.tesla.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Host kamai-apigateway-warpdashboardapi.tesla.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

how i can redirect not found: replay to /dev/null

Comment: If you absolutely want to redirect to /dev/null: `host $i | grep "not found" > /dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "not found" message isn't being written to stderr, so you can't filter it by redirecting.

You can use `grep -v` to filter it out.

```
for i in $(cat no-http.txt) ; do host "$i" ; done | grep -v 'not found'
```

Answer (score 2):

The NOT found causes `host` to return 1 so test its return code.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while read -r name; do
  if reply=$(host "$name"); then
    printf '%s\n' "$reply"
  fi
done <no-http.txt
```